# IN list in subquery and mainquery leads to duplication

Tags: postgresql

I started out with a query that gives me all shifts for a person.

```
SELECT
  p.id as person_id, json_agg(sh) as shifts
FROM
  people as p,
  (SELECT s.id, s.date_of_shift, s.shift_type_id
  FROM people as p
  LEFT JOIN shifts as s
  ON s.person_id = p.id AND s.date_of_shift BETWEEN '2016-02-11' AND '2016-02-17'
  WHERE p.id = 2001
  ORDER BY p.id
  ) as sh
WHERE
  p.id = 2001
GROUP BY
  p.id
;
```

the result would be something like this:

```
 person_id |                              shifts                              
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------      
2001       | [{"id":580069,"date_of_shift":"2016-02-11","shift_type_id":44},+
             {"id":580070,"date_of_shift":"2016-02-12","shift_type_id":42}, +
             {"id":580071,"date_of_shift":"2016-02-15","shift_type_id":49}, +
             {"id":580072,"date_of_shift":"2016-02-16","shift_type_id":41}, +
             {"id":580073,"date_of_shift":"2016-02-17","shift_type_id":48}]
```

so I got 1 row, the first column is the person id and the 2nd is the json with the array of shifts.

The next step would be, to give the query a list of person_ids and get something like this

```
person_id | shifts
----------|--------------
2001      | [{..},]
2002      | [{..},]
2003      | [{..},]
```

so I ran this:

```
SELECT
 p.id as person_id, json_agg(sh) as shifts
FROM
 people as p,
 (SELECT s.id, s.date_of_shift, s.shift_type_id
 FROM people as p
 LEFT JOIN shifts as s
 ON s.person_id = p.id AND s.date_of_shift BETWEEN '2016-02-11' AND '2016-02-17'
 WHERE p.id IN (2201,2202,2203)
 ORDER BY p.id
 ) as sh
WHERE
 p.id IN (2201,2202,2203)
GROUP BY
 p.id
;
```

The problem is that I now get all shifts for every person inside the subquery.
So in this case I get 15 shifts for every person_id, instead of 5.

I understand why I get this result, but I'm stuck on how to get the result I'm look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [**`LATERAL`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) join:

```
SELECT p.id as person_id, json_agg(sh) as shifts
FROM people as p,
LATERAL  (  
  SELECT s.person_id, s.date_of_shift, s.shift_type_id
  FROM shifts as s
  WHERE s.person_id = p.id AND 
        s.date_of_shift BETWEEN '2016-02-11' AND '2016-02-17') as sh
WHERE p.id IN (2201,2202,2203)
GROUP BY p.id;
```

This way the subquery is simplified: you don't to perform a `LEFT JOIN` operation inside it, as you can access table `people` that lies outside the scope of the subquery.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c7df3/5)

If you want to *always* get *all* rows of table `people` irrespective if there are matching rows in `shifts` table, then you can use a `LEFT JOIN LATERAL`:

```
SELECT p.id as person_id, json_agg(sh) as shifts
FROM people as p
LEFT JOIN LATERAL  (  
  SELECT person_id, date_of_shift, shift_type_id
  FROM shifts) as sh
  ON sh.person_id = p.id AND 
     sh.date_of_shift BETWEEN '2016-02-11' AND '2016-02-17'     
WHERE p.id IN (2201,2202,2203, 2204)
GROUP BY p.id;
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bd24e2/8)

Comment: this works almost perfectly. except that I don't get and an empty shift json, when I have no shift matching the date. thats why i had the condition in the on clause

Comment: it is 10 times faster, than my solution with active record in rails. awesom!